# LINQ find records that are different in two separate tables

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables that are identical. One is live data and the other is staging data.

They both have the same unique key constraint on two columns.

Using Linq, is it possible to get a list of records in `Production` that differ in `Staging`?

The table looks like this:

```
string name
string number
timespan timeIn
timespan timeOut
.
snip
.
string lastDay
```

Like I said, both tables are identical and I want only the records where the columns [after] `name` and `number` differ from the same record in the `Production` table assuming that `name` and `number` comprise the primary key.

**edit**

Is it simply a long query with `&&` and `!='s`?

Comment: Override the **Equals()** method for your record type.

Comment: Pieter, do you mean the linq Equals method or one that i might have written?

Comment: I mean: Override the **Equals()** method supplied by **object** as the (default) definition of _value equality_ for your record type, so as to define _value equality_ properly for your record type. Only you know how to properly define _value equality_  for your record type; anything pre-packaged will always have to guess between _reference equality_ and _value equality_ for properties.

Comment: @Pieter I think that will only work with linq2objets, not if they are using something like linq2sql or linq2entities which implied since they are querying tables.

Comment: @AaronLS: You are correct. I had the right idea, but the wrong implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ `join` and `where` clauses in combination - something like this:

```
from s in Staging
join p in Production on new {s.name, s.number} equals new {p.name, p.number}
where s.timeIn != p.timeIn || s.timeOut != p.timeOut || s.lastDay != p.lastDay
select s
```

I have only included columns you showed after `name` and `number` of course - not those you snipped, but you get the idea.

The [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907099.aspx) has more information on joining using composite keys.

Comment: Yeah I kinda suspected something like this but hoped there might have been a better approach

Comment: Roger that.  I would be interested in a better way as well - always. :)

Answer (score 0):

Their is an Except clause that will give you all of the records in production, except those that are identical, hence what is different in production.  Note that means there could be records in Staging that are different, but you won't see them.  J0e3gan's query does the opposite, showing only staging records that differ from production.

If you want to see all the difference, you really need to run the query twice, reversed each time, and then union them.  This is the same technique you'd use in SQL with the EXCEPT statement.

```
db.production.Except(db.staging);
```

or more like

```
db.production.Except(db.staging).Union( db.staging.Except(db.production) );
```

Note this will probably only work if the entity type of staging and production are identical.  You may need to do this

```
db.production.Except(db.staging.Select(s=> new ProductionEntity{ id = s.id, name = s.name, lastDay = s.lastDay ,etc. });
```